# TypeScript: Change type definition of string properties to numbers

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have an interface A defined like this:

```js
interface A = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

How can I create a generic type that for any given interface, transforms all `string` properties to `number`?

Output

```js
interface B = {
  firstName: number;
  lastName: number;
  cretedAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `type` for `B` instead, you can map over the keys of A and conditionally use `number` if the value at that key is originally `string`.

```
interface A {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}
type B = {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends string ? number : A[K]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define it as a template,

```
interface A<T> = {
    firstName: T;
    lastName: T;
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

Then when you define it as a string implements `A<string>` or `A<number>`